# pivot ACCESS with subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, pivot-table

need some help here…
I manage to make running with MS-ACCES a query which integrate subquery.

```
SELECT
    TS3.YearTimeSheet, 
    Ress1.[Complete Name], 
    Rates2.[Applicable Currency], 
    Rates2.[Applicable Rate], 
    TS3.WeekTimeSheet, 
    Sum(TS3.TotalWeek) AS [Total Hrs], 
    Sum([TotalWeek]*[Applicable Rate]*(1+[WAO])) AS [Cost Incl WAO]
FROM 
    (
        [Resources Rates] AS Rates2
        INNER JOIN Resources AS Ress1 ON Rates2.StaffID = Ress1.STAFFID
    ) 
    INNER JOIN TimeSheets AS TS3 ON Ress1.STAFFID = TS3.STAFFID
WHERE Rates2.[Applicable Rate] = (
    SELECT [Resources Rates].[Applicable Rate] 
    FROM [Resources Rates] 
    WHERE  
        [Resources Rates].[StaffID]= [Rates2].[StaffID]
        AND DatePart('yyyy', [Resources Rates].[Starting Date]) = [TS3].[YearTimeSheet] 
        AND NOT DatePart('ww', [Resources Rates].[Starting Date])>=[TS3].WeekTimeSheet 
        AND NOT DatePart('ww', [Resources Rates].[Ending Date])< [TS3].WeekTimeSheet
    )
GROUP BY
    TS3.YearTimeSheet, 
    Ress1.[Complete Name], 
    Rates2.[Applicable Currency], 
    Rates2.[Applicable Rate], 
    TS3.WeekTimeSheet;
```

Unfortunately while trying to transform it into a Pivot… error!
"Le Moteur de la base de données Microsoft Access be reconnait pas "TS3.WeekTimeSheet" en tant que nom de champ ou expression correcte." In English Access does not recognise TS3.WeekTimeSheet being a field.

My understanding goes that declaration of this variable is at the end of the instruction and therefore cannot be used before? It works in a normal Subquery… in a TRANSFORM PIVOT instruction. Certainly wrong method… Please Help
the below SQL instruction however works When I force the criteria with static data. I doing certainly something wrong in the structure with the below.
I was thinking the below should do the job. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
TRANSFORM Sum(TS3.TotalWeek) AS WeekSum

SELECT TS3.YearTimeSheet,
  Ress1.[Complete Name], 
  RatesBis.[Applicable Currency], 
  RatesBis.[Applicable Rate], 
  Sum(TS3.TotalWeek) AS [Total Hrs], 
  Sum([TotalWeek]*RatesBis.[Applicable Rate]*(1+[WAO])) AS [Cost Incl WAO]

FROM Resources AS Ress1 INNER JOIN TimeSheets AS TS3 ON Ress1.STAFFID = TS3.STAFFID, 
  (
  SELECT [Resources Rates].[Applicable Currency], [Resources Rates].[Applicable Rate] 
  FROM [Resources Rates] 
  WHERE [Resources Rates].[StaffID]=Ress1.STAFFID
   AND NOT DatePart('ww', [Resources Rates].[Starting Date])>= TS3.WeekTimeSheet
   AND NOT DatePart('ww', [Resources Rates].[Ending Date])< TS3.WeekTimeSheet
   ) AS RatesBis

GROUP BY 
  TS3.YearTimeSheet, 
  Ress1.[Complete Name], 
  RatesBis.[Applicable Currency], 
  RatesBis.[Applicable Rate]

PIVOT TS3.WeekTimeSheet;
```

Comment: Which error do you get when you execute the SQL query ?

Comment: Hi, Error is "Le Moteur de la base de données Microsoft Access be reconnait pas "TS3.WeekTimeSheet" en tant que nom de champ ou expression correcte." In English Access does not recognised TS3.WeekTimeSheet being a field.

Comment: My understanding goes that declaration of this variable is at the end of the instruction and therefore cannot be used before? It works in normal Subquery... in a TRANSFORM PIVOT instruction. Certainly wrong method… please help